# How to perform double buffering with atomic pointers?

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic

Atomic newbie here. My code currently looks like this (simplified):

```cpp
std::atomic<Object*> object;

void thread_a()
{
  object.load()->doSomething(); // (1)
}

void thread_b()
{
    Object* oldObject = object.load();
    Object* newObject = new Object();
    // Update new object accordingly...

    while (!object.compare_exchange_weak(oldObject, newObject));

    delete oldObject;
}
```

In words, my idea is to let `thread_b` atomically swap the shared object (double-buffering), while `thread_a` performs some work on it. My question: can I safely assume that the shared object will be "protected" against data races while `thread_a` calls `doSomething()` on it, as done in (1)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The fetching of the pointer with `load()` will be atomic, but the call to `doSomething()` itself will not be atomic.

That means the pointers could be swapped after `load()` is called but before `doSomething()` is called (which means `doSomething()` is called on the wrong and now deleted object).

Perhaps a mutex could be a better choice here?

Comment: Yes, a mutex would definitely be a better/easier choice :) However I'm trying to investigate the lock-free way of doing this kind of things. Is the atomic double-buffering not doable in your opinion?

Comment: @Ignorant IMO not the way you have implemented it anyway. Perhaps if you used smart pointers instead. Then the worst that could happen is that you call `doSomething()` on an object that isn't "active" but at least it will still exist.

Comment: Smart pointers are the key here. The `Object` on which `.doSomething()` is called must obviously survive at least to the end of `.doSomething`, so `thread_b` can never call `delete`. It simply doesn't know where `thread_a` is.

Answer (score 4):

I do this quite often, but... with shared pointers, and it's lock-free!

There's a problem with your design, as Some Programmer Dude suggested in his answer. But if you do this with `shared_ptr`, and your program logic allows it, you'll be fine.

The reason why this works with `shared_ptr` is that your object will not be deleted by force, as long as it lives somewhere else. So, this is how you do it:

```
std::shared_ptr<Object> object;

void thread_a()
{
  std::atomic_load(&object)->doSomething(); // (1)
}

void thread_b()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Object> oldObject = std::atomic_load(&object);
    std::shared_ptr<Object> newObject = std::make_shared<Object>();
    // Update new object accordingly...

    while (!std::atomic_compare_exchange_weak(object, oldObject, newObject));
}
```

EDIT: This `atomic_load` is specialized for the `shared_ptr`. This seems to have caused confusion in the comments: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic

Comment: are you sure this is valid/defined code? for `atomic_load` from cppreference: `T atomic_load( const std::atomic<T>* obj )` -> "Atomically obtains the value pointed to by obj as if by obj->load()". your object is not an atomic object?!

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but this is not safe as well. The object can be deleted after load, before call to `doSomething`. Don't you need to copy the `std::shared_ptr` to a local variable in `thread_a`? In order to increment the underlying reference counter.

Comment: Additionally to the answer of phön : Isn't it possible that `object` gets destroyed in between the `std::atomic_load(&object)` and the constructor call of `oldObject`?

Comment: Seems like `std::atomic_load` has specializations for `std::shared_ptr`. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic . I didnt know this. With this on the table, it seems this is safe code, the last line just has 2 syntax errors: `std::atomic_compare_exchange_weak(object, oldObject, newObject)` needs to be `std::atomic_compare_exchange_weak(&object, &oldObject, newObject)`, if i am not misstaken.

Comment: @freakish The atomic load will return a new shared_ptr, which is alive to the end of the full expression. So you kinda get a local shared_ptr copy, just without a name.

Comment: @MikevanDyke Of course you have to make sure that your shared pointer object is alive the whole time. If you meant the pointed to object inside the shared pointer, then no. Lifetime of the object inside the shared pointer is guaranteed to last as long as shared pointers are alive.

Comment: @phön Yes, there's a specialization of for `shared_ptr`. I just saw your message. I'm not so familiar with `exchange_weak`, so I'm not sure about the syntax (but fixing it is trivial, which is why I didn't care that much). Glad you learned something from my answer ;-)